# How to join two models?

Tags: xamarin

I am getting data from one model but there is a need to get data from other model. How would i do that?
Is there something like join in SQL?

```
public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string NameCz { get; set; }
        public string NameEng { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Droppable { get; set; }
        public int CategoryGroupId { get; set; }
    }
```

I need that so i can filter my list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep an Instance of category in Article model,

```
 public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string NameCz { get; set; }
    public string NameEng { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Category category{get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Droppable { get; set; }
    public int CategoryGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

While fetching data from the db, you can join tables with CategoryId and fetch records for both Article and Category.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from Article a join Category c on a.CategoryId = c.Id